# over quota error while getting ip address from the http://jsonip.appspot.com/?callback=? in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the user's IP address. For this i am using the below code:

```
  var jqxhr = $.getJSON("http://jsonip.appspot.com?callback=?",
                    function (data) { 
                        alert(data.ip);        
                    })
        .error(function () { alert("error"); })
```

At start i was able to get the IP but now it is not. Its giving

> Over Quota. This application is temporarily over its serving quota. Please try again later

Please help me how can get rid of this or please suggest me some other option that can helpful to fetch IP by using jquery or javascript.

Comment: I have no idea why that service is necessary. Detecting and returning the user's IP is like 3 lines of code max in any server side programming language.

Comment: Yes it is easy to find IP address in server side programming.But i need it in javascript or jquery

Comment: jsonip.appspot.com is not JS or jQuery. Just replace the url with a link to your own version of it.

Comment: @Juhana: The DMZ configuration is blocking to get real user IP Address

Answer (score 4):

The solution you're using here is to use someone else's free lookup service via JSONP. However, with free service you get no guarantees on uptime or performance.  This is something that someone cooked up, and is not actively maintaining at this time.

The code is run on presumably google's free app, which has a quota system. Although the quota is fairly generous (5 million pageviews / month) it seems that it's exceeded its allotment.  See https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/general#quota for a more detailed explanation.

Your permanent solution shouldn't rely on free services.

Having said that, this should work for you:  `http://jsonip.com?callback=?`

That service is limited to IPV4, but beggars can't be choosers, I suppose. Writeup: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2278874